# ACL in joomla (access control list)?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

would any one may please elaborate following statement bit further

```
"In this helloworld-example the actions to which access is 
controlled are divided in   three sections: at the component
level, the category level and the item level"
```

what is meant by component level access, category level access and item level access.

copied from

```
http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Adding_ACL#Describing_the_actions_you_want_to_control_the_access_to
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the description of Joomla ACL waterfall hierarchy:

```
|- Global configuration
   |- Component level
      |- Component category level
         |- Item Level (in default extensions only content articles)
```

So by default Component inherits all permissions from Global configuration, Category inherits from Component and Item from a Category where's located.

You may overwrite any rules at any level and these propagate down to levels below:

- If you disable *edit* rights in component configuration for *Managers* group, they won't be able to edit any items.
- If you do it in category level, they won't be able to edit items in that category
- Disable editing rights for item applies only to that item